# Independent subqueries in SQL to Linq statement (hit DB only one time)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Having something similar to:

```
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) from Table1),(SELECT COUNT(*) from Table2 )
```

How do I write it in linq? Or is it simple not possible?

**Limitations**:

- Can only hit the database one time:

  ```
     var result = new {
                   Sum1 = db.Table1.Count(),
                   Sum2 = db.Table2.Count()
                  });  // is not valid.....
  ```
- I do not want to use something similar to (using a "helping" table):

  ```
  var result = (from t3 in db.Table3
               select new {
                   Sum1 = db.Table1.Count(),
                   Sum2 = db.Table2.Count()
               }).firstOrDefault();
   //In order to get only the first row 
   //but it will not return nothing if the table 3 has no entries......
  ```
- Not using `db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

Comment: Why is that first statement not valid?

Comment: @Magnus I didn't use any SQL profiler, but I think this is generating two "independent" queries and not the SQL statement I am looking for.

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: @Magnus it matters for my real purpose.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should include the _real_ purpose in the question so that we may more accurately help you.

Comment: You *are* writing two seperate queries. When you use Subqueries in SQL, it executes the queries independently and returns the results. If there is a way to do this in linq without executing two queries, i would be suprised

Comment: @DavidColwell yes, perhaps it is not possible to do it in linq. I'm just not sure about it.

Comment: Well, there is a way to do it, but it is *horrible* on performance. You could join the two tables using an outer join and count the distinct IDs... but if you do that, please get a vasectomy

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL is not SQL or a replacement for SQL. It's a query language and ORM, and your query doesn't involve any objects. In general, ORMs are not suited when you need aggregates or combining unrelated data

Comment: Bottom line is: you can't select _from nothing_ with LINQ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot see a solution which solves all your limitations. This is one of the caveats with using an ORM-mapper, you are not in control of the generated SQL.

In this case, if it is utterly unacceptable for you to send more than one query to the database, the harsh truth is that you will have to write the query yourself.

**Update**

I got curious and created an extension method that can do this! Of course it constructs its own SQL command, and it just works for Linq2SQL. Also massive disclaimer: It's fairly dirty code, if I have some time I'll fix it up in the weekend :)

```
public static TOut CountMany<TContext, TOut>(this TContext db, Expression<Func<TContext, TOut>> tableSelector)
        where TContext: DataContext
    {
        var newExpression = (NewExpression) tableSelector.Body;
        var tables =
            newExpression.Arguments.OfType<MethodCallExpression>()
                         .SelectMany(mce => mce.Arguments.OfType<MemberExpression>())
                         .ToList();
        var command = new string[tables.Count];
        for(var i = 0; i < tables.Count; i++)
        {
            var table = tables[i];
            var tableType = ((PropertyInfo) table.Member).PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var tableName = tableType.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>().Name;
            command[i] = string.Format("(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}) AS T{1}", tableName, i);
        }

        var dbCommand = db.Connection.CreateCommand();
        dbCommand.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT {0}", String.Join(",", command));
        db.Connection.Open();
        IDataRecord result;
        try
        {
            result = dbCommand.ExecuteReader().OfType<IDataRecord>().First();
        }
        finally
        {
            db.Connection.Close();
        }

        var results = new object[tables.Count];
        for (var i = 0; i < tables.Count; i++)
            results[i] = result.GetInt32(i);
        var ctor = typeof(TOut).GetConstructor(Enumerable.Repeat(typeof(int), tables.Count).ToArray());
        return (TOut) ctor.Invoke(results);
    }
```

the code is called like this:

```
var counts = dbContext.CountMany(db => new 
                                       {
                                           table1Count = db.Table1.Count(),
                                           table2Count = db.Table2.Count()
                                           //etc.
                                       });
```

Comment: I still didn't try it, but at first sight I will give you (at least) a vote up just for your effort and motivation to find an answer :)

Comment: Thanks x) I misread your question though, and thought you were using Linq2Sql, not entity framework, so my code won't integrate seamlessly with yours :/ Although only the fetching of tableName and of dbCommand should be different!